# LDAP Search on multiple fields

Tags: ldap

I know the answer is probably no, however, I figured before I give up I may as well ask.

Say I have 3 attributes in my LDAP... fullname, sn and givenname... and for whatever reason the administrator, or the person who is doing the entry enters a person's "fullname" as lastname, firstname (sn, givenname), however, I want to do a search for firstname lastname (givenname sn).

Is it possible to create a filter something like this:

```
(&((givenname sn)=Bob Smith))
```

I've tried that and it obviously doesn't work. This is a new requirement for my application and I don't have the power to change how the fullname is stored in the LDAP.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just search for

```
(&(givenName=Bob)(sn=Smith))
```

No need to trouble about the fullname attribute at all.

Comment: Unfortunately the end users cannot be bothered to enter in first and last name into separate fields. I had to do some "magic"; since you're the only one to answer I'll accept yours as "most correct".

Comment: You can make a constraint so that they have to, with the OpenLDAP constraint overlay.